# Find the coordinates of the markers on Google Maps

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I've developed an iOS application which is using Google Maps API and is drawing some markers. What I need now is to find the coordinates of every marker drawed on the map view. I tried to find something in the documentation of Google Maps but I don't think that I found what I needed so I would be very happy if I get some help.

Comment: How are you drawing the markers to begin with without co-ords ?

Comment: In another file where I receive JSON data from Google Directions.

Comment: Doesn't that file have the co-ords ?

Comment: Not sure if you're a genius or I'm so dumb. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON file you are receiving from Google Directions contains the co-ordinates. You just need to loop over the all markers array.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over the `allMarkers` array and inside the loop do something like

```
var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().lat();
var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().lng();
```

tips:

- [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) docs
- [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) `getPosition()`.

Comment: This is the documentation for JavaScript.

Comment: I thought you were trying to do it with js, sorry :/